# UIScrollView in tvOS

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, tvos

I have a view hierarchy similar to the one in the image below (blue is the visible part of the scene):

[image]

So I have a UIScrollView with a lot of elements, out of which I am only showing the two button since they are relevant to the question. The first button is visible when the app is run, whereas the other one is positioned outside of the initially visible area. The first button is also the preferredFocusedView.

Now I am changing focus between the two buttons using a UIFocusGuide, and this works (checked it in `didUpdateFocusInContext:`). However, my scroll view does not scroll down when Button2 gets focused.

The scroll view is pinned to superview and I give it an appropriate content size in `viewDidLoad` of my view controller.

Any ideas how to get the scroll view to scroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved this by setting `scrollView.contentSize` to the appropriate size in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: my scrollview seems to cut of the bottom part(part thats invisible on start) of the view i placed inside my scrollivew :(

Comment: add in viewDidLayoutSubviews
`override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.page_scroll_view.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1920, 1780)
}`

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `UIScrollView.panGestureRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes`. It is an array of `NSNumber` with values based on `UITouchType` or `UITouch.TouchType` (depending on language version). By default `allowedTouchTypes` contains 2 values - `direct` and `stylus`. It means that your `UIScrollView` instance will not response to signals from remote control. Add the following line to fix it:

**Swift 4**

```
self.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes = [NSNumber(value: UITouchType.indirect.rawValue)]
```

**Swift 4.2 & 5**

```
self.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes = [NSNumber(value: UITouch.TouchType.indirect.rawValue)]
```

Also, don't forget to set a correct `contentSize` for `UIScrollView`:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 1920.0, height: 2000.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add pan gesture recognizer. I learned from here: http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/gesture-recognizer-using-swift. I added more code to make it not scrolling strangely, e.g. in horizontal direction.

```
var currentY : CGFloat = 0   //this saves current Y position

func initializeGestureRecognizer()
{
    //For PanGesture Recoginzation
    let panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("recognizePanGesture:"))
    self.scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
}

func recognizePanGesture(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer)
{
    let translate = sender.translationInView(self.view)
    var newY = sender.view!.center.y + translate.y

    if(newY >= self.view.frame.height - 20) {
        newY = sender.view!.center.y    //make it not scrolling downwards at the very beginning
    }
    else if( newY <= 0){
        newY = currentY                 //make it scrolling not too much upwards
    }

    sender.view!.center = CGPoint(x:sender.view!.center.x,
        y:newY)
    currentY = newY

    sender.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
}
```